# Create bootable USB with boot manager to dual-boot Windows and Android x86

Tags: windows-10, boot, multi-boot, bootloader, android-x86

I tried to install Remix OS (Android x86) on my Windows 10 computer.

Unfortunately it overwrote my current bootloader and now I can't boot into Windows nor the newly installed Android. What should I do to be able to dual-boot Windows and Android x86?

Is there any software, which could be transfered to USB to create a bootable USB in order to dual-boot on my computer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use boot repair to install a grub that permit you open android or windows at start your computer.

> 1. Download [BOOT-REPAIR-DISK](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files),
> 2. Then burn it on a live-USB key via Rufus or Unetbootin. (do not burn it on CD/DVD if your PC came with Windows8/10)
> 3. Insert the Boot-Repair-Disk and reboot the PC,
> 4. Choose your language,
> 5. Connect internet if possible
> 6. Click "Recommended repair"
> 7. Reboot the pc --> solves the majority of bootsector/GRUB/MBR problems

Source [boot-repair-disk / Home / Home](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/)